# php artisan make:model --resource gives model parameter function in controller. how to use them?

Tags: php, laravel

> php artisan make:model --resource -m

is giving me functions in controller. i didnt understand how to use them.
This is what controller has after running above command.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\test1;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class Test1Controller extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            //
        }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\test1  $test1
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(test1 $test1)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\test1  $test1
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(test1 $test1)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\test1  $test1
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, test1 $test1)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\test1  $test1
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(test1 $test1)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

how to use these?

but i know

> php artisan:make controller --resource

will provide functions in the controller with $id parameter and i know how to use them.
This is what the controller has in it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class test2 extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There something in Laravel that called "Route-model" binding, in this case your route should look like this:

```
/test1/{test1} //instead of /test1/{id}
```

And you can access the object without using `find` or `where`:

```
public function show(test1 $test1)
{
    // The $test1 is accessible and you can get any property you want like $test1->id;
}
```

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: How do $test1 gets the value?